# Invalid text representation symfony

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, converters

I'm trying to use ParamConverter in symfony2. But i have this error:

`An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.logo AS logo_1, t0.interest AS interest_2, t0.period AS period_3, t0.amount AS amount_4, t0.created_at AS created_at_5, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_6, t0.url_pattern AS url_pattern_7, t0.annotation AS annotation_8, t0.first_loan_free AS first_loan_free_9, t0.max_value AS max_value_10, t0.rrso AS rrso_11, t0.id AS id_12, t0.advertisement_status_id AS advertisement_status_id_13, t0.advertiser_id AS advertiser_id_14 FROM advertisement t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params ["go"]:`

I don't know why my controller tries to `SELECT` from my entity with params `"go"`. I tried to solve this problem, but i don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
Any sugestions?

This is my entity:

```
/**
 * Advertisement
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="advertisement", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_C95F6AEEBA2FCBC2", columns={"advertiser_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_C95F6AEE138EAC6A", columns={"advertisement_status_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Advertisement extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="advertisement_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    protected $id; 

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="logo", type="blob", nullable=true)
 */
protected $logo;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="interest", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
 */
protected $interest = '0';

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="period", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
protected $period;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
 */
protected $amount;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
protected $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
protected $updatedAt;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="url_pattern", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $urlPattern;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="annotation", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $annotation;
.
.
.
```

And this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace AffiliateBundle\Controller;


use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AffiliateBundle\Entity\Lead;
use AffiliateBundle\Entity\Advertisement;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;



/**
 * Catch controller.
 *
 * @Route("catch")
 */
class CatchController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @ParamConverter("advertisement", class="AffiliateBundle:Advertisement")
     */
    public function goAction(Advertisement $advertisement)
    {

        //Creating new Lead      
        $lead = new Lead();
        $lead ->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $lead ->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $add = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $add->persist($lead);
        $add->flush();            
        //Taking id of the created lead
        $leadId = $lead->getId();
        //Saving cookie in user's browser
        $cookieValue = array(
            'name' => 'leadcookie',
            'value' => $leadId
        );
        $cookieLead = new Cookie($cookieValue['name'], $cookieValue['value']);
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookieLead);
        return $this->redirect('http://xyz.pl');

    }

}
```

Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What url are you opening in your browser? `/go` perchance?

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your code albeit I haven't used the SEQUENCE strategy before. I am assuming you are using Oracle possibly? One thing I do see is that you aren't giving your routes a name such as @Route("/{id}", "index") . Since this action seems to be default of your controller, id name it "index" i.e. indexAction. Also in the context you are using the Paramconverter, that declaration isn't even needed since it should be able to type-hint from your route.

Comment: Wow I'm really dumb. I was opening affiliate/catch/go instead of affiliate/catch/{some id number}. Case closed.